# VSCode. расширение которое автоматически закрывает тэг при первом же '/' к примеру <div / и сразу закрывает его

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, веб-программирование, visual-studio-code

Я дааааааааааавно хотел уже закрыть этот вопрос для себя. В webstudio эта функция встроена. А в vscode Даже автоизменение тэгов самое поплуряное расширение имеет оценку 3/5 и барахлит иногда. Так что я не знаю как найти такое расширение которое сразу закрывало тэг при написании слэша. Очень полезно было бы, спасибо!!!

Comment: [emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)?

Comment: та не) я про то что к примеру у меня <Image ...здесь куча всего/> и я удаляю по все после слова Image, тэг у меня обрезанный получился и его в конце нужно будет закрыть, и когда я закрываю его мне приходится делать непривичное мне действие ставить и / и > что двойная работа, которой не было в webstorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть плагин **Auto Close Tag** подойдет
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag

Comment: Сэр, вы выйграли номенацию - лучший ответ! Поздравим победителя господа!